# Why do I get a RuntimeBinderException using json.net with dynamic when calling a method

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net

Why is it that when I use dynamic with json.net I get a runtime binding exception then calling a method without casting but I can do assignments not problem

```
private static void Main()
{
    dynamic json = JObject.Parse("{\"Test\":23}");
    var t = json.Test;
    int a = t; //Success
    Prop = t; //Success
    Func(t); //RuntimeBinderException
}

private static void Func(int i){}

private static int Prop { get; set; }
```

When I cast it to the correct type there are no errors but I would prefer to not have to do that. Am I doing something wrong, is this a problem in the json.net library or is a language restriction.

Edit:
This is to solve a problem where I don't have control over the methods signature and I don't want to cast it on every call.

Comment: Can you please post the full exception message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `json.Test` returns a `JValue` and `JValue` has a dynamic `TryConvert`. So if you do an implicit static conversion by pointing it to an `int` or cast to an `int` it will at runtime call that `TryConvert` and you have success. However if you use that dynamically typed variable in a method argument, the c# runtime looks for a method named `Func` with an argument that best matches 'JValue' it will not try to call 'TryConvert' for every permutation of a possible method (even if it's only one) thus you get the runtime binding error.

So the simplest solution is to just cast on every call or set a statically typed variable each time you want to pass a `JValue` as an argument.

There is actually a more general question and answer of this same issue too if you are looking for more info: 
[Pass a dynamic variable in a static parameter of a method in C# 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057751/pass-a-dynamic-variable-in-a-static-parameter-of-a-method-in-c-sharp-4)

Comment: This helped me a huge lot. Thank you very much. What a weird behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

private static void Func(dynamic i){}

will solve the issue.

Comment: yes but what do I do when I don't have control over the signature of the method I'm calling.